# Firebase Crashlytics does not support NDK?

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

When you want to use **Crashlytics NDK**, you need call `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(),new CrashlyticsNdk());` But Firebase Crashlytics calls 
`Fabric.with(context, new Kit[]{new Crashlytics()});` on startup.
As the result you cannot use Crashlytics NDK.

How can I avoid this problem?

```
public class CrashlyticsInitProvider extends ContentProvider {
private static final String TAG = "CrashlyticsInitProvider";

public CrashlyticsInitProvider() {
}

public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = this.getContext();
    FirebaseInfo firebaseInfo = new FirebaseInfo();
    CrashlyticsInitProvider.EnabledCheckStrategy enabledCheckStrategy = new ManifestEnabledCheckStrategy();
    if (this.shouldInitializeFabric(context, firebaseInfo, enabledCheckStrategy)) {
        try {
            Fabric.with(context, new Kit[]{new Crashlytics()}); // !here
            Fabric.getLogger().i("CrashlyticsInitProvider", "CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful");
        } catch (IllegalStateException var5) {
            Fabric.getLogger().i("CrashlyticsInitProvider", "CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization unsuccessful");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Then initialise Crashlytics manually in your `Application` subclass:

```
Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())
                .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#enable_debug_mode

Comment: Where does the `CrashlyticsNdk` come from? It's not included in the `implementation com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5` firebase crashlytics dependency.

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko In your `build.gradle`: `implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }`

Comment: What does firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled do? Why disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK crash reports are already supported by Firebase Crashlytics SDK. After you set up Crashlytics with the Firebase Crashlytics SDK, you can add the followings to your `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the Crashlytics NDK dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.0.0-beta01'
}

// …
android {
    // ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Add this extension
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                // Enable processing and uploading of native symbols to Crashlytics
                // servers. By default, this is disabled to improve build speeds.
                // This flag must be enabled to see properly-symbolicated native
                // stack traces in the Crashlytics dashboard.
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports-new-sdk