# Firebase Crashlytics and NDK Native Crashes

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, crashlytics

I have been trying to get Crashlytics to capture native/fatal/C++ crashes for our Unity project. I was able to get it to work for iOS without much effort. Also, it works for non-fatal exceptions in Android. I see the exceptions on the Console. However, if I crash the app from C++ code (e.g segmentation violation or raising a signal), I do not have any crash logged in the console.

To have native crashes working, I started by just adding a dependency on the CrashlyticsNDK .aar (*com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-ndk-2.1.0*), but no luck. Searching on the internet, I found that I might need [initialize Fabric myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986823/firebase-crashlytics-does-not-support-ndk). So I added the meta-data line in the manifest to disable automatic initialization, and added the following code in our *Activity.onCreate()*:

`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());`

I see in the logs that auto-initialization is skipped. Still, no fatal crash being logged in the console.

I decompiled all those .aar files to try to understand what's going on. I found that whenever we disable auto-initialization, *io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.java* goes through a whitelisting logic that removes the CrashlyticsNdk kit from the list! It prints the following message in the logs:

```
08-01 22:07:14.278: W/Fabric(20797): Fabric will not initialize any kits when Firebase automatic data collection is disabled; to use Third-party kits with automatic data collection disabled, initialize these kits via non-Fabric means.
```

Then, I tried to hack the Fabric initialization by pretending the data collection is on during initialization only, as follow:

```
DataCollectionArbiter.getInstance(this).setCrashlyticsDataCollectionEnabled(true);
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
Fabric.getLogger().i("MyCrashlyticsInit", "My crashlytics initialization successful");
DataCollectionArbiter.getInstance(this).setCrashlyticsDataCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Now, I can see some interesting log lines:

```
08-01 22:45:39.356: I/FirebaseInitProvider(24353): FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-01 22:45:39.362: I/CrashlyticsInitProvider(24353): CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization
08-01 22:45:39.404: D/libcrashlytics(24353): Initializing libcrashlytics version 2.0.5
08-01 22:45:39.404: D/libcrashlytics(24353): Initializing native crash handling successful.
08-01 22:45:39.419: I/CrashlyticsCore(24353): Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
08-01 22:45:39.427: I/MyCrashlyticsInit(24353): My crashlytics initialization successful
```

So, when I crash the app and run it again, I get the log line below:

```
08-01 22:45:39.489: W/CrashlyticsCore(24353): Received null settings, skipping report submission!
```

I have the impression the crash was handled correctly, but Crashlytics could not upload the crash data because of invalid/null settings.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. Getting Crashlytics to work has to be much simpler, and I have the feeling I've done something wrong along the way.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I was too verbose. Just wanted to show the whole context.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you followed all the instructions here: https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk? Also, I believe that last log line to be a red herring - not sure that I've ever seen that affect anything, but good to know. Initializing your app via that doc, crashing the app from a segfault of some sort, and relaunching the app should be all that it takes.